# Как правильно сказать, в римской цифре VII два стоит позади пяти или в начале?

Tags: грамматика

Я считаю, что позади, муж уверяет, что это начало, так как мы пишем слева направо.

Answer (score 1):

VII — два стоит *после* пяти (и потому прибавляется). Для сравнения: IX — один стоит *перед* десятью (и потому отнимается).